# Files and folders sorted strangely when in file select

Tags: nautilus, 14.10

I don't know why but previously when I was looking for file to open (for example in gedit), the folders were appearing before the files, but now they are sorted no matter if they are files or folders.

How can I change this behaviour ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `File Manager`. Then go to `Edit -> Preferences -> View`. Here, you need to activate `Sort folders before files`.

Comment: I had the option checked, but by unchecking and checking again it does the trick.